# Custom style for INPUT type Number with arrows and label inside the input CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make an custom input type=number with only CSS. The arrows should be like the image and the inputs need to have a text label, in which case user's clicking on the arrows will increment only the number.
Any idea if this is possible through pure css?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is the closest I could get. A larger number will overlap the "días"...

```css
.input {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  color: grey;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.plazo {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 120px;
  background: #ffffff;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 4;
  color: grey;
}

.number:before {
  content: "días";
  position: absolute;
  left: 55px;
  top: 38px;
  color: grey;
  z-index: 5;
}

.asterix {
  color: red;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  opacity: 1;
  background: white;
}

.number-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.number-wrapper:after,
.number-wrapper:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.number-wrapper:after {
  color: gray;
  content: "\25B2";
  transform: scale(2, 1);
  top: -1px;
}

.number-wrapper:before {
  color: gray;
  content: "\25BC";
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  bottom: -.5em;
  transform: scale(2, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="plazo">Plazo de termino<span class="asterix">*</span></div>
<div class="number">
  <span class='number-wrapper'>
    <input type="number" placeholder="60" class="input">
</span>
</div>
```

Second version, where the input expands, and doesn't overlap the "días":

```js
$(function() {
  $('#hide').text($('#txt').val());
  $('#txt').width($('#hide').width());
}).on('input', function() {
  $('#hide').text($('#txt').val());
  $('#txt').width($('#hide').width());
});

/*credit: https://codepen.io/komarovdesign/pen/PPRbgb/ */

jQuery('<div class="quantity-nav"><div class="quantity-button quantity-up">&#x25B2;</div><div class="quantity-button quantity-down">&#x25BC;</div></div>').insertAfter('.number-wrapper input');
jQuery('.number-wrapper').each(function() {
  var spinner = jQuery(this),
    input = spinner.find('input[type="number"]'),
    btnUp = spinner.find('.quantity-up'),
    btnDown = spinner.find('.quantity-down'),
    min = input.attr('min'),
    max = input.attr('max');

  btnUp.click(function() {
    var oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
    if (oldValue >= max) {
      var newVal = oldValue;
    } else {
      var newVal = oldValue + 1;
    }
    spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
    spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
  });

  btnDown.click(function() {
    var oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
    if (oldValue <= min) {
      var newVal = oldValue;
    } else {
      var newVal = oldValue - 1;
    }
    spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
    spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
  });
});
```

```css
.number {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  max-width: 400px;
  color: grey;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.plazo {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 157px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 35px;
    z-index: 4;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.asterix {
  color: red;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: inner-spin-button !important;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}

.number-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.number-wrapper:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: gray;
  content: "diás";
  font-size: 20px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 18px;
}

.input {
  top: 60px;
  text-indent: 20px;
  left: -20px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#txt {
  border: none;
  color: #888;
  min-width: 40px;
  top: 9px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 320px;
  padding-right: 10px
}

#txt:focus-visible {
  outline: none;
}

#hide {
  display: none;
  white-space: pre;
}


/*plus*/

.number-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

input[type=text]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=text]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=text] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.number-wrapper input {
  width: 45px;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 1.65;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.number-wrapper input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.quantity-nav {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 42px;
  top: 9px;
}

.quantity-button {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  line-height: 1.7;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  bottom: -.5em;
  transform: scale(2, 1);
}

.quantity-button.quantity-up {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  top: 0;
}

.quantity-button.quantity-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  height: 50%;
}

.quantity-button.quantity-up,
.quantity-button.quantity-down {
  right: -400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plazo">Plazo de termino<span class="asterix">*</span></div>
<div class="number">
  <span class='number-wrapper'>
    <span id="hide"></span><input type="number" class="input" id="txt" value="60" contenteditable="true">
  </span>

</div>
```